# output the result of a query of a database?

Tags: php

Hello i got a problem with my mysql code it gives the following error upon trying to output:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in     C:\xampplite\htdocs\learncent\acksearch\search.php on line 25
```

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","acksocial");

if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
printf("Connection failed:%s \n",mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['search']);
$table = 'acksearch';

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = $name", MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {

    // $row is an associative array

    // Do something here

echo "Name: ".$row['name'];

echo " country: ".$row['country'];


}

$db->close();
?>
```

EDIT: 
added 1 more } and no error but it wont output the result?

Would be good if anyone could help me.

EDIT AGAIN : Now  the code look like this

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","acksocial");

if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
printf("Connection failed:%s \n",mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['search']);
$table = 'acksearch';

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = $name", MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{

// $row is an associative array

// Do something here

echo "Name: ".$row['name'];

echo " country: ".$row['country'];

}
```

The error its giving its:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampplite\htdocs\searcher.php on line 25
```

Thanks Fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not close the while loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {

    // $row is an associative array

    // Do something here

echo "Name: ".$row['name'];

echo " country: ".$row['country'];

}///// I added this } here
```

you need to add `}` after the last row.

Comment: added 1 more } and no error but it wont output the result?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if somewhere a `}` is missing.

In your case there should be a second `}` prior to `$db->close();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close one more brace "}" before you end "?>"

Comment: It wont still output the result of the query since im using a form where i would be enable to send it here and then i searches the db for the input and if not null it would output result in the page ?